# Proving the existence of a negative eigenvalue in a Sturm-Liouville Problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, reference-request, spectral-theory, sturm-liouville

Does anybody have any good references on the spectral theory of time-independent Schrödinger equations?

In particular, I'm looking at an equation of the form with,

$$ -y''(x)+q(x)y(x)=\lambda y(x) $$

on $(1,\infty)$ with a potential $q(x)$ that has the properties $q(1)=0$, $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}q(x)=C\in \mathbb{R}_+$, but in particular $q\not\in L^1(1,\infty)$. I would like to know under what conditions, I can infer the existence of a negative eigenvalue $\lambda$. A reference which discusses this situation would be ideal.

Comment: If $q$ is locally integrable on $(1,\infty)$, then you can solve the equation for all real and complex $\lambda$. You need conditions on $y$ at some point(s).

Comment: @DisintegratingByParts Thanks for your reply, I have y vanishing at the end points of the domain. Do you have a reference that I can explore?